# Coupling between field components in waveguides

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, maxwell-equations, waveguide

I've been reading on Jia-Ming Liu's Photonic Devices and I came across this part:

[image]

I don't understand the highlighted part: in a TE mode we know that $E_z=0$, but the other components may be non-zero. Since $\epsilon$ lies in the $(x,y)$ plane, then so does $\nabla \epsilon$. With this information alone, it is impossible to reach to the conclusion that $\nabla \epsilon \perp E$. How come they state that?

Comment: http://library.navoiy-uni.uz/files/jia-ming%20liu%20-%20photonic%20devices%20(2005)(1104s).pdf p. 80 For anyone wanting to check in context. I did not come to a different conclusion than Bidon.

Comment: These are not necessary but sufficient conditions for decoupling; check out the LSE/LSM modes of rectangular waveguides